# why can't we have concrete implementation of base interface in aggregation?

Tags: c#, oop

While implementing an interface, why can't we have concrete implementation of base interface in aggregation?

Which OOP, principle is violating here? `StorageEntitySas` is essentially of type IStorageEntitySas

```
public interface IValetKeyResponse
{
    IStorageEntitySas Sas { get; set; }
    string UploadUrl { get; set; }
}

public class ValetKeyResponse : IValetKeyResponse
{
    //Which OOP, principle is violating here? StorageEntitySas is essentially of type IStorageEntitySas
    **public StorageEntitySas Sas { get; set; }**
    public string UploadUrl { get; set; }
}

public class StorageEntitySas : IStorageEntitySas
{
    public string Credentials { get; set; }
    public Uri BlobUri { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Suppose it was `interface ICage { Animal Contents { get; set; } }`. You are asking why `class Aquarium : ICage { public Fish Contents { get; set; } } ` is illegal. Is it now clear why?

Comment: thanks @Eric helped.

Comment: Now, suppose you had *just the getter*. Now there's no *logical* problem with your scheme. That's just a feature that C# does not support. The feature you want is called *return type covariance*, and it's a long-requested feature of C#. If you really want it, go to the github forum and advocate for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setter on the `Sas` property allows you to provide any implementation of `IStorageEntitySas`. This means you should be able to do:

```
public class OtherStorageSas : IStorageEntitySas { ... }

IValetKeyResponse r = new ValetKeyResponse();
r.Sas = new OtherStorageSas();
```

This would not be type-safe if allowed since `ValetKeyResponse.Sas` has an incompatible type `StorageEntitySas`.

Answer (score 3):

An interface defines a *contract* that every implementing class has to fulfill. It defines what a method has to return and which parameters you may use. In particular, users of your interface don't know - and don't *have to* know anything of the concrete classes, which is an implementation detail.

However you're still able to do the following:

```
public class ValetKeyResponse : IValetKeyResponse
{
    public IStorageEntitySas Sas { get; set; } = new StorageEntitySas();
    public string UploadUrl { get; set; }
}
```

So why is this not allowed? Imagine you have an API that simply returns the interface-type.

```
IValetKeyResponse response = myClass.GetValetResponse();
// what am I allowed to pass here when I don´t know the actual class of response?
response.Sas = ...
```

A client of this API doesn´t know which class you actually get and thus which kind of `IStorageEntitySaS` you´re allowed to assign to that instance. That´s what the contract defines, it sais you can pass anything that implements `IStorageEntitySas`.